# Create an AngularJS module if it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several directives and factories spread over several files but I want all of them to be included inside the same module. For example:

**user-account.js**

```
var userModule = angular.module("user", []); //I create the module here
userModule.directive("userPicture", ...);
```

**user-transactions.js**

```
var userModule = angular.module("user"); //I use the module here
userModule.directive("userPayment", ...);
```

The problem I have is for this to work I need to include the files in the right order, otherwise it won't work since the creation of the module is only done in user-account.js. I don't like this since users for these modules would need to know the proper order for it to work.

So my question is, how can I structure my modules creation + usage in an elegant way? I was thinking on creating some kind of Singelton helper to create the module if it doesn't exist but I don't love the idea. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix the `user` module and the `user-account` in the same file.

**app.js**:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['user']);
```

**user.js**:

```
angular.module('user', []);
```

**user-account.js**:

```
angular.module("user").directive("userPicture", ...);
```

**user-transactions.js**:

```
angular.module("user").directive("userPayment", ...);
```

And then in your **index.html**:

```
<!-- modules -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/user.js"></script>

<!-- directives -->
<script src="js/directives/user-account.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/user-transactions.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using requirejs in that case. Then you won't have to worry about ordering of your script files.

Answer (score 0):

I am following the style from the book [Mastering Web Application Development with Angularjs](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app), the link is the whole example explained in the book.

The main idea of this style is 
1. Dived code by businsess feature instead of by type;
2. Put everything from one module into one file, like:

// myApp.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['user']);
```

//user.js

```
angular.module('user', [])
.directive("userPicture", ...);
.directive("userPayment", ...);
```

//index.html:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/user.js"></script>
```

Why doing that is no matter directives, service or controllers, they are talking to each other, in one file you don't need to switch files.

Yes, you may bloat up the model file, but it is good sign to separate into another model.

I am using that style in my projects, and I found the code much readable than before.